# Getting the right request id when a user follows an invite

Tags: facebook-graph-api, query-string

I don't understand why, when the user follows an invite sent to them from the new request dialog, we get a comma separated list of all the request ids they have been sent.  This means I do not know which one they have clicked on.  How do I know this?

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for the [requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) and the [requests in general](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/)

Your app receives a list of all requests that the current user has outstanding for your app, you can then show your own interface for them to accept them all

Comment: I dont want to accept them all - I want to accept one. They are inviting their friends into groups or teams, so if they have a list of requests from different people, I need to know which one they accepted and delete the others.

Comment: You don't know which button they clicked; display all the outstanding requests to them and let them choose in your own app's interface

Comment: That's what I figured, that seems crazy.  That's making me have a whole new user screen asking them which invite they want to accept, when they had clearly just clicked on the one they want to accept already.  Great user journey....